# WP: подключение js скриптов только определенным ролям

Tags: wordpress

Есть целая группа ajax-скриптов, которая на фронте нужна только главным ролям (т.е. админы и модераторы, например). И я бы не хотел выставлять эти скрипты в общий доступ, путем обычного подключения.

Можно ли как-то (и как?) подключить скрипты только для определенных ролей, а еще лучше фильтровать по роли + странице (post_id и post_type)?

Речь о правильном подключении с регистрацией скрипта в функциональном файле темы.

Comment: Правильнее не по ролям определять а по возможно сям (can)

Answer (score 0):

Никаких проблем

```
$user          = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array( 'moderator', 'administrator' );
$allowed_pages = array( 10, 15, 42 );
if ( array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {
    if ( is_page( $allowed_pages ) ) {
        // запуск скриптов
        // wp_enqueue_script( ... );
    }
}
```